# IBM Cloud Object Storage Java Client - IllegalArgument exception

Tags: ibm-cloud, java, object-storage

I'm following sample provided here https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/cloud-object-storage/libraries/java.html#java

Created the following code:

```
SDKGlobalConfiguration.IAM_ENDPOINT = "https://iam.bluemix.net/oidc/token";

String bucketName = "mybucket_name";
String api_key = "api_key_taken_fro_the_service_credential_json";
String service_instance_id = "service_id_taken_from_the_bucket_policies_page";
String endpoint_url = "http://s3.mel01.objectstorage.softlayer.net";
String location = "mel01";

System.out.println("Current time: " + new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()).toString());
_cos = createClient(api_key, service_instance_id, endpoint_url, location);
listObjects(bucketName, _cos);
listBuckets(_cos);
```

the `listObjects` and `listBuckets` are exact c&p from that referred page.

I'm getting Invalid argument exception, as follows:

```
Listing objects in bucket mybucket_name
[INFO    ] FFDC1015I: An FFDC Incident has been created: "com.ibm.cloud.objectstorage.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Invalid Argument (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidArgument; Request ID: 3bb36c4c-8de4-4f39-98f4-a1bfd3aa8972), S3 Extended Request ID: null com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init 181" at ffdc_18.04.12_13.02.15.0.log
[ERROR   ] SRVE0271E: Uncaught init() exception created by servlet [gas.servlet.BlmxS3Servlet] in application [s3]: com.ibm.cloud.objectstorage.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Invalid Argument (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidArgument; Request ID: 3bb36c4c-8de4-4f39-98f4-a1bfd3aa8972), S3 Extended Request ID: null
    at com.ibm.cloud.objectstorage.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1588)
    at com.ibm.cloud.objectstorage.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1258)
    at com.ibm.cloud.objectstorage.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1030)
    at com.ibm.cloud.objectstorage.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:742)
    at com.ibm.cloud.objectstorage.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:716)
    at com.ibm.cloud.objectstorage.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:699)
    at com.ibm.cloud.objectstorage.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:667)
    at com.ibm.cloud.objectstorage.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:649)
    at com.ibm.cloud.objectstorage.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:513)
    at com.ibm.cloud.objectstorage.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3635)
    at com.ibm.cloud.objectstorage.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3582)
    at com.ibm.cloud.objectstorage.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3576)
    at com.ibm.cloud.objectstorage.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.listObjects(AmazonS3Client.java:761)
    at gas.servlet.BlmxS3Servlet.listObjects(BlmxS3Servlet.java:94)
    at gas.servlet.BlmxS3Servlet.init(BlmxS3Servlet.java:63)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
    at [internal classes]
```

What argument might be invalid? No clue from the log nor ffdc.

UPDATE
The bucket name is correct, otherwise I'm getting:

```
[ERROR   ] SRVE0271E: Uncaught init() exception created by servlet [gas.servlet.BlmxS3Servlet] in application [s3]: com.ibm.cloud.objectstorage.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The specified bucket does not exist. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 404; Error Code: NoSuchBucket; Request ID: bf299e50-1aac-4af7-89df-188eb4b7c60f), S3 Extended Request ID: null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were several issues during configuring this:

1) You need to create credential with additional properties of {"HMAC":true}

2) For the configuration use:

- `apikey` -  apikey entry from the credential
- `service_instance_id` - this is a bit misleading - as it is your Object servcie name, not id - in my case it was string `Cloud Object Storage-abc`
- `endpoint_url` - bucket endpoint - in my case `http://s3.mel01.objectstorage.softlayer.net` - make sure that it is `https` and that you imported certificates to your truststore.

Then is should work. 
Listing buckets is not working for me still due to "Access Denied", so I have to check the permissions for the service ID.

Answer (score 0):

your endpoint_url should be over https instead of http